Keep Taskbar Icons even if app open/in use?
In Windows 11, is there a way to keep the pinned taskbar apps' icon showing, even when the program is open?

As you can see, when I open PowerBI and Chrome, it keeps my Outlook icon sort of "hidden" in between.  How can I keep the icons on the left, and then open apps on the right side of the app icons?
Essentially, I'd like it to work like the Quick Launch Toolbar we used to be able to do. (I haven't seen workarounds to add this back in Win 11).  When I open an app, it keeps the icons on the left, and shows the open app to the right of all the links.

You can create a new shortcut using cmd /c "path to exe", give that shortcut the right icon, and pin that shortcut to your taskbar. It will then always launch a new instance of your program.

@LPChip - Do you have any more detail? I did the cmd ... and it just opened Excel. I did find the location (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe) and created a shortcut, and then right click -> Show More Options -> Pin to Taskbar.  It put the shortcut there, but it acts like the regular "pinned" icons.  I open Excel, and that pin on the taskbar shows the filename. Clicking it also just opens the Excel file, not a new instance.

So your shortcut now says CMD /C "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe" right?

@LPChip -- Aha! I see what you mean. Yes, now it launches an 'empty' instance of Excel.  Do you know how I can get the CMD to close once Excel (or whatever program I choose) opens?

Now I'm thinking, to do that (close the CMD window when the program launches), am I moving into like, making a .bat territory?

you can try using this: CMD /C "start C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe"

@LPChip - I get "Windows cannot find 'C:\Program'. Make sure you typed the name correctly..."

ah. Try CMD /C "start ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe"""

@LPChip - Now it's doing same, but with "...cannot find 'Files\Microsoft'".  (Note: If you want to make this in to an answer, it seems the best viable option so far, even with my Google-fu, etc. this seems to be the most promising way to do it).

I'll write you an answer once we confirmed what method works. Can you try CMD /C "start """" ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe"""

You may also be interested in Windhawk. Specifically the "Disable grouping on the taskbar" mod. This is one of the things I specifically installed it for after moving to Win 11 and losing the Quicklaunch toolbar.

You can create a shortcut somewhere on your C drive, and inside put the following:
CMD /C "start """" """C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe"""

CMD /C will start any program or command available in command prompt that is inside the quotes. To escape a quote, so you can use parameters with a space, you use "".
In the above example, I used excel as the command exchange shown that you wanted to test with that.
The command start is used because that will start a process in parallel mode, and immediately returns the handle back to cmd without it needing to wait for the program to close, which will spawn a cmd window, but then immediately after, close the window.
The command start has 2 parameters, the first one is windows title, but should be optional, and the second one is program.
Once the shortcut works, give it an icon and proper name, then right-click it, and pin to taskbar.

Still getting "Windows cannot find 'C:\Program' .  Make sure you typed...." :/ Edit: Aha! I just added quote to the start of the Excel path, C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "start """" """C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe""" and it works! :D

Glad you got it working. I was pretty sure it was a quotes problem, so I wrote an answer so I could use better formatting.

I really appreciate your help on this! Now I can get closer to reliving the glory days of XP :P

You're welcome. :)
